# Ruby on rails: How to display information from another table?

Tags: html, ruby, associations

Updated: 22/08/2019
This is working now. Thanks for feedback and help!

Image of Benefit list: [List Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V78WG.jpg) <-- Needed to params permit benefit_ids

Old Version: 21/08/2019

I have set up many to many associations but can't get the data table name. I can get the ID but it won't allow me to display the other fields information.

I have looked in the controller and added to permit benefit_ids but not sure if I should add anything else to it.

```
exercisetypes(Index.html.erb)
 --- Old code (21/08/2019)
<tbody>
    <% @exercisetypes.each do |exercisetype| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= exercisetype.name %> </td>
    <td><%= exercisetype.benefits.name %> </td>
...

 ---
New code (22/08/2019)
    <tbody>
    <% @exercisetypes.each do |exercisetype| %>
      <tr>
        <td> <%= exercisetype.name %> </td>
          <td>
           <ul>
            <% exercisetype.benefits.each do |benefit| %>
            <li><%= benefit.name %></li>
           <% end %>
          </ul>
         </td>
    <% end %>
    ...


  _form.html.erb(Gem: simple form)

  <% f.association :benefits, as: :check_boxes %>
```

```
Models

exercisetype.rb
  has_many :exercisetype_benefits, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :benefits, :through => :exercisetype_benefits


benefit.rb
  has_many :exercisetype_benefits
  has_many :exercisetypes, :through => :exercisetype_benefits


exercisetype_benefit.rb
  belongs_to :exercisetype
  belongs_to :benefit
```

The table displays the model name Benefit. There are no error messages but I am not sure how to display the name of the benefit.

Answer (score 0):

`exercisetype.benefits` is a collection:

```
# index.html.erb
<ul>
  <% exercisetype.benefits.each do |benefit| %>
    <li><%= benefit.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey Panic, thanks for the reply. I have edited the original HTML code. I will try to understand yours as well as I am still not too sure yet.

Comment: Hey Panic, Thank you I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Benefits belongs to exercisetype model, so you need to iterate over benefits to access the attributes. Check this:

```
<tbody>
  <% @exercisetypes.each do |exercisetype| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= exercisetype.name %> </td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <% exercisetype.benefits.each do |benefit| %>
            <li><%= benefit.name %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey Gustavo, Thanks for the help I will work on it now.

Comment: Hey Gustavo, Thanks for the explanation it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Exercise has_many benefits which mean when you do exercise.benefits it will return a collection of benefits object so you need to iterate through it.

Your collection will look like

```
`#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Benefit id: 1,  name: "Good Health">, #<Benefit id: 2, name: "Blood flow">]>`
```

So you need to iterate through it like.

```
<% exercisetype.benefits.each do |benefit| %>
    <li><%= benefit.name %></li>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Hey Saif, Thanks for the reply I will check it out now.

Comment: Hey Saif, it is working I am getting one item from benefit. But if I select multiple items it comes up as blank. Sorry I am fairly new to this so not sure what parts I need to be looking at. Thanks

Comment: First you need to add more than multiple items in benefit.
For Example from your rails c: exercisetype.benefits.create(name: "Health")
Then reload your page and see if you've this benefit listed

Comment: Hey Saif, In my benefit Index.html I have for example Health, Leg muscles and Neck Muscles. In the Exercise type index.html it can show one of the items but when I click all 3 and save it will display a blank. I have added a picture as well just incase. Thanks for your help

Comment: Couldn't find any picture

Comment: Oh sorry, I put it at the top called List Display as a hyperlink.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the latest code.

Comment: Hey saif, do not worry. I was foolish and forgot that I played around with permit forgot to change it back to normal. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hey, your code looks fine. Does it show more than one benefits for a single exercisetype ?

Comment: Cool. Good luck.